# Haskell: General type of function pushing element to a list

Tags: haskell

Given a general function

```
cons x xs = x:xs
```

How would one give it a general type? I tried doing

```
cons:: a -> [b] -> [c]
```

But it does not seem to work

Comment: You can always type `:t cons` in ghci and see the result. By the way you can express it in a more concise manner: `cons = (:)` so it is the sane as, and has the same type as, `(:)` which is a data constructor of `[a]`.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you for your input. I was more interested in what kind of type should be given to `cons` rather than the actual function itself

Comment: The type that can/should be given to a function is intimately connected to how that function is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list is defined as (pseudocode):

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

Therefore a list can only contain **elements of the same type**: either it is an empty list (`[]`) so it does not contain any elements, or it is a CONS (`:`) and then the head is of type `a` and so is its tail `[a]`.

Therefore if you define:

```
cons x xs = x : xs
```

Haskell takes a look at the signature of the constructor: `a : [a]`. So it derives that `x` is an `a`, `xs` is an `[a]`, and `(x:xs)` is an `[a]` as well (the head of the `data` statement).

As a result, the most general type signature of `cons` is:

```
cons :: a -> [a] -> [a]
cons x xs = x : xs
```

You cannot define a `cons` with `x :: a` and `xs :: [b]` (with `a` different from `b`) since in that case you invoke the constructor `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` with conflicting types.

In Haskell, you usually do not *have to write type signatures*. If you omit them, Haskell will fill in the most generic one. You can use `:t` in the `ghci` interactive shell to obtain the type of a function. Like:

```
Prelude> let cons x xs = x : xs
Prelude> :t cons
cons :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Finally note you do not need to define a `cons` function, you can simply use `(:)`:

```
cons :: a -> [a] -> [a]
cons = (:)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Remember, `a` and `b` are potentially different types, and here you want to be able to add an `a` to the list.  So, you want both lists to be type `[a]`.

```
cons :: a -> [a] -> [a]
cons = (:)
```